# Check if li contains the specified string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an array 'name'. I need to check if the elements in this array are present in the list in html.

The code in php is as follows:

```
foreach ($name as $value2) {
  echo "<script>
  if($('li:not(:contains(\"".$value2."\"))'))
     {
       alert('".$value2." does not  exists');
     }  
  else
     {
       alert('".$value2." exists');
     }
  </script>";
 }
```

But I am getting the alerts as the value does not exist for every element.

Comment: The string 'li:not(:contains(\"".$value2."\"))' is always truthy; I suspect you intended to wrap that in $( ... ) .

Comment: also, drop the quotes around `$value2` and `json_encode` it instead. it's safer

Comment: And swap the statements so you can save a not

Comment: Question doesn't show the HTML that outputs the list elements. Please add this.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use PHP Arrays :**

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

**[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)**

You can try like this :

```
 <?php foreach ($name as $value2) {  ?>
 <script>
  if($('li:not(:contains(\"" <?php echo $value2; ?>"\"))'))
     {
       alert('"<?php echo $value2; ?>" does not  exists');
     }  
  else
     {
       alert('"<?php echo $value2; ?>" exists');
     }
  </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: How would that find the LIs on the page?

Comment: Surinder's solution is right in the first place. You would not  do this in javascript when you're outputting this in PHP with which it's a lot easier to check what you want.

Comment: Thank u so much for the help... But i am not understanding how to use jquery here? I am making the same mistake in my code perhaps in jquery. Can u please elaborate.

Comment: You need to post more code. `if('li:not(:contains(\"".$value2."\"))')` What is li? When was that selected? `if('li:not(:contains(somevalue))')` isn't valid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot test the content of the html on the server (after ajax or something for example), it is not good practise to create

```
<script>
.
</script>
<script>
.
</script>
<script>
.
</script>
```

when you can do

```
$jsString = implode("','", $array);
$jsString = "'".$jsString."'";
?>
<script>
var vals = [<? echo $jsString; ?>];
var contains =[],notContains=[],liContains=[];
$.each(vals,function(i,val) {
  var li = $('li:contains("'+val+'")');
  if (li) {
    contains.push(val); // all vals presents
    liContains.push(li); // all (sets of) LIs with the vals
  }
  else {
    notContains.push(val); // all vals not present
  }
});
 alert(contains.length);
</script>
```